# How to prevent additional code in functions.php to be removed once there is an update?

Tags: plugins, functions

Every time storefront is being updated, my additional functions.php code is being removed.

How to prevent additional code in functions.php to be removed once there is an update?

Is there a plugin or is the only way to do it to create a child theme which in itself is a debug-worthy approach?

Comment: What do you mean debug-worthy approach?

Answer (score 2):

There isn’t a way. You need to create a child theme or a plugin and put the functions there.

Note that there’s nothing special about child themes. The point is to put the code into something that somebody else isn’t going to update. So third party child themes aren’t safe either.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a child theme of course, but I recommend you to use the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin. Here you can add PHP which will run exactly like adding it to the child theme functions.php. However it is much more organised, and is retained once you make an update.